# create multiple rectangle dynamically in windows phone

Tags: c#, dynamic, windows-phone-8.1, multiple-instances, rectangles

I have created a canvas and I want to let user create rectangle/s on the screen and then user should be able to manipulate it.

I have written the following code -

```
    private TranslateTransform move = new TranslateTransform();
    private ScaleTransform resize = new ScaleTransform();
    private TransformGroup rectangleTransforms = new TransformGroup();

    private Brush stationaryBrush;
    private Brush transformingBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Height = 100;
        rect.Width = 100;
        SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
        rect.Fill = myBrush;
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(rect);
        rectangleTransforms.Children.Add(move);
        rectangleTransforms.Children.Add(resize);
        rect.RenderTransform = rectangleTransforms;

        // Handle manipulation events.
        rect.ManipulationStarted +=
            new EventHandler<ManipulationStartedEventArgs>(Rectangle_ManipulationStarted);
        rect.ManipulationDelta +=
            new EventHandler<ManipulationDeltaEventArgs>(Rectangle_ManipulationDelta);
        rect.ManipulationCompleted +=
            new EventHandler<ManipulationCompletedEventArgs>(Rectangle_ManipulationCompleted);
    }

    void Rectangle_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        rect.Fill = stationaryBrush;
    }

    void Rectangle_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        stationaryBrush = rect.Fill;
        rect.Fill = transformingBrush;
    }

    void Rectangle_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        move.X += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
        move.Y += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;

        if (e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X > 0 && e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y > 0)
        {
            resize.ScaleX *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X;
            resize.ScaleY *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y;
        }
    }
```

I copied this code from MSDN Library.
I have declared a rectangle object(rect) above.

Now my problem is this code is working fine for one rectangle but I want to give use an option to add another or multiple rectangles.

1.is it possible to create multiple rectangle with same button click event and let the user manipulate each rectangle create or something where he can adjust the rectangle atleast one time after creating it and not afterwards.

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'd just have to get the `Rectangle` instance from the "sender" in the event handler, rather than storing a local copy:

```
void Rectangle_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var rect = (Rectangle)sender;
    rect.Fill = stationaryBrush;
}
```

The same applies to "move" -- don't use a local variable, but create a new instance in each button click event:

```
var rectangleTransform = new TransformGroup();
rectangleTransforms.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform());
rectangleTransforms.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform());
rect.RenderTransform = rectangleTransforms;
```

You can retrieve it in the "ManipulationDelta" handler by casting the `RenderTransform` property back to the `TransformGroup` type:

```
void Rectangle_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    var rect = (Rectangle)sender;
    var move = (TransformGroup)rect.RenderTransform;
    // etc
```